# Ubuntu - Group users create new files/directory always: -rwxrwxr-x / drwxrwxr-x

Tags: ubuntu, chown, permissions, groups

I got a directory in which my group is the owner. The group has two users, however, when a user create a directory the other user can't move the files.

Why is that and how can I change so that the users within a group can move each other files?

Now I have to chown everytime I need to move another users files which is very ineffective...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the directory itself mode 2775 (ie, turn on the group sticky bit).  This should mean that people creating a directory or file in that directory by virtue of their group ownership will have the resulting files group-owned by that group, with the group sticky bit set (if it's a directory), and group-writeable (unless their umask forbids it, or they manually `chmod` it, and there's not much you can do about that except tell them not to), which will enable other group members to edit/delete files.

Comment: Thanks man! It works, they wont manually chmod so this should work then :)

Comment: As long as their umask is 002, not (eg) 022, yes, it should.  Glad to help!